# How to treat Brettanomyces for secondary fermentation?

Tags: beer, techniques, secondary-fermentation, sour, brettanomyces

I'm wanting to add some Brettanomyces lambicus to an old ale after it has been moved to a secondary fermentor (it should be in the 7-8% ABV range at this point, and the primary yeast will be Wyeast 1968, if that matters).   Do I need to make a starter for it, or can I just dump the culture directly into the beer, cap the fermentor, and let it go for the rest of the year?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for a starter when its going to be sitting there for that long.  Just time is all that's needed.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I think you can just dump it right in, with no starter.

**Warning:**  I suggest that you double your normal sanitizing procedures with everything that comes in contact with the Brett.  A couple of years ago I added the dregs from a couple of bottles of Orval to a batch, and the Brett showed up in quite a few of my subsequent batches.  I dumped out probably 15 gallons of beer due to this.

Comment: oh this better bottle will be used for sour beers from now on.

Comment: But don't forget hoses, etc.

Comment: putting aside my general dislike of most sour beers, the potential to introduce the bacteria into later beers is an excellent point I had never considered, thanks.

Comment: Yup.  I consider myself to be pretty careful, and my sanitation procedures had always been adequate... until I introduced Brett into my homebrewery.